# Web Reporting Solution without Reporting Services?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, reporting

I'm working on a solution to create reports in a web application but don't have the budget or personnel to manage a SQL Server Reporting Services install. What alternatives do I have, given these constraints?

I'm using ASP.NET 3.5 on SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 5):

You could use SSRS but in local mode not server mode. From my understanding you don't need SSRS when reports are rendered with this method. You will also be required to write more code to support the reports.

Other options then include looking at other reporting packages out there. Crystal Reports is one possibility but if you can't manage SSRS, I'm guessing CR would not be a possibility.

Anyways here's some links for SSRS in local mode:

http://www.vbdotnetheaven.com/UploadFile/justinsaraceno/Main11132006012727AM/Main.aspx
http://aspalliance.com/1318_Using_Local_Microsoft_SQL_Server_Reporting_Services_in_ASPNET

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use Jasper:  http://jasperforge.org/

I believe there is a jTDS driver to connect to sql server.

I have no clue if this will work or is supported, just an idea.

Answer (score 0):

HTML is a reporting layer. Do you need another one?

Comment: It is a layout layer, but you are in trouble when you try to insert the notion of pages inside the infinite canvas (at least if you want to do it right)